# When using a select2 dropdown as an editor in an incell editing kendo grid it causes the cell to prematurely leave edit mode?

Tags: kendo-grid, jquery-select2

I think it has to do with how select2 creates the actual dropdown outside of the  element it is based on.

Is there a way to suspend the cells "blur" activity until the user has made a selection, or in general just make the select2 more usable inside the kendo grid?

I hastily made this jsfiddle.  I put the select2 inside the first column.

```
function testEditor(container, options) {

var customInput = $('<select name="' + options.field + '" data-text-field="text" data-value-field="id" />');

    var scheduleContactSelect =
        customInput
        .appendTo(container)
        .select2(
        {
            data: ["test1", "test2"]
        });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zaq3a3o5/

As you can see, the moment you start interacting with the select2, the cell closes edit mode but leaves the select2 hanging.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out the solution was three parts.

1. Use the "dropdownParent" select2 config option to make sure it appends the disconnected dropdown part inside the same element.
2. Make sure you are using Select2 4.03 or higher. (I had to upgrade to 4.03)
3. Define the "focusout" event while inside the "select2:open" event for the select2 search box so we can preventDefault() and stopPropagation() to prevent "focusout" from bubbling up.